# What is the dimensionless central potential in a King Model?

Tags: astrophysics

King Models are commonly used to model stellar clusters. I understand that they are described by a surface brightness profile $$ \Sigma (r) = \frac{\Sigma (0)}{(1+r/r_0)^2} $$ as described [here](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~aam/science/thesis/total/node20.html).

In the literature, a 'central dimensionless potential' $W$ is quoted, which appears to describe the King model. How is $W$ related to the surface brightness profile? Also is this the correct description of a King Model - I seem to get conflicting reports on the web?

Comment: Could you provide one of the articles (author+title or link) in which this potential is quoted?

Comment: Is $W$ similar to the $˜r$ described [here](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~george/ay20/eaa-starclus.pdf), defined as $˜r \equiv r/r_0$?

Comment: You should add some more information to your question. For example: where did you get that equation from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give this a try, though I don't have the time or inclination to work through the gory details myself. I'll start by defining the notation I'll use:

Poisson's equation:
$$\nabla^2\Phi({\bf x}) = 4\pi G \rho({\bf x})$$

Define a new potential by a constant offset, where $\Phi_0$ is the potential at infinity:
$$\Psi=-\Phi+\Phi_0$$

And define the velocity dispersion (which is a constant in the King model):
$$\sigma^2 = \langle v^2\rangle/3$$

The radial density profile (radial in the spherical sense) is:

$$\rho(r) = \rho_0\left[e^{\Psi/\sigma^2}{\rm erf\left(\frac{\sqrt{\Psi}}{\sigma}\right)}-\sqrt{\frac{4\Psi}{\pi\sigma^2}}\left(1+\frac{2\Psi}{3\sigma^2}\right)\right]$$

This needs some work before being useful. Apparently the trick is to insert it into Poisson's equation and solve for $\Psi$ using the boundary conditions $\Psi(r=0)=\Psi_0$ and $\left.\frac{{\rm d}\Psi}{{\rm d}r}\right|_{r=0}=0$.

Then I *think* the dimensionless central potential is:
$$W=\Psi_0/\sigma^2$$

You could then get the surface density profile (which in this case is the same as the surface brightness profile) by doing something like this:
$$\Sigma(R) = \lim_{\Delta R \rightarrow 0}\frac{2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_R^{R+\Delta R}\rho(r)\,R\,{\rm d}z\,{\rm d }R}{2\pi \left[\left(R+\Delta R\right)^2-R^2\right]}$$

I think there's a way to write that integral without the limit, but this is what I managed to scribble down off hand. From there you should be able to see how $W$ comes in.

Hopefully that helps, and please let me know if/when you figure out definitively what $W$ is.

My reference for all this (other than the parts that came out of my head, e.g. that last integral) is [Mo, van den Bosch & White](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010gfe..book.....M).